# set meta viewport width but not show all content

Tags: html, mobile, viewport

I was building a non-responsive website whose minimum width is 1600px. How to center all content and let all content be visible while viewing on mobile? I set the meta viewport to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1600">`, but the content is not center on mobile. And there is a horizontal scrollbar appeared. (on iphone 5) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>` to render the web page in respect to the mobile display.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if I use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>`, the result would be like this: [http://imgur.com/U0cp6SC](http://imgur.com/U0cp6SC), the content is bigger than the viewport. But I expected it to look like: [http://imgur.com/Z9iR7nn](http://imgur.com/Z9iR7nn), all content is inside the viewport. I had tried `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1600>` but not working. (The width of my page is 1600px.)

Comment: My mistake. I didn't understand what you were trying to do. Try:     `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1600, initial-scale=1">`